# Как получить в PDO объект?

Tags: php, pdo

Есть запрос:

```
$db = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE email=:email');
$db->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->execute();
$User = $st->fetchAll();
```

Суть в том, что в переменной $User в итоге оказывается просто массив, с которым потом удобно работать в процедурном стиле. А как быть если я хочу что бы результат выборки из БД был представлен в виде объекта?

Comment: судя по всему, вы ищете ORM

Comment: @etki не совсем, ORM это следующий шаг, в ней есть конструктор запросов уже, а тут запросы я сам пишу

Comment: Конструктор запросов не является обязательной частью ORM. ORM как понятие - это именно переложение табличных данных на внутриязыковые объекты.

Comment: вам какой объект то нужен, stdClass или User какой-нибудь?

Comment: хотя без разницы, `$st->fetchObject('User')` экземпляр нужного класса вернет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что бы получить объект надо сделать так:

```
$db = $pdo->prepare(" SELECT `email` FROM `user` ");
$db->execute();
$User = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$Test = $User->fio;
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($Test); echo '</pre>'; // тут строка
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($User); echo '</pre>'; // тут объект
```

Answer (score 4):

> `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` создает и возвращает объект запрошенного класса,
>   присваивая значения столбцов результирующего набора именованным
>   свойствам класса, и следом вызывает конструктор, если не задан
>   `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE`

```
$st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
$users = $st->fetchAll();
```

Можно также использовать [`$st->fetchObject('User')`](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchobject.php)

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` - Таки для этого надо чтоб был класс. А если у него обычная кастомная выборка не под какой класс?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а если у него обычная кастомная выборка не под какой класс, то он сам себе злобный буратина. Не надо так :)

Comment: @rjhdby то есть если я выбираю в одном запросе `count` количество юзеров по какому-то признаку + минимальное,максимально и среднее значение, а также относится ли это значение к какому-то типу, которое можно получить внутри выборки лишь за счет `IF` или `SWITCH` - то надо класс делать? Что-то ерунда какая-то

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тогда у меня к вам вопрос - зачем ЭТО помещать в объект? Несомненно бывают исключительные ситуации, когда разработчик заранее не знает структуру данных, которая будет ему возвращена. Но в подавляющем большинстве случаев это говорит только о том, что что-то не так с архитектурой.

Comment: @rjhdby `зачем ЭТО помещать в объект?` - единообразие стиля? Всё - объект, а не всё - как получится))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну эдак можно дойти и до `$math = new Math();$a = $math->add($b, $c);` для сложения 1+1  Во всем надо меру знать :)))

Comment: @rjhdby можно. есть же калькуляторы на `jquery` :D  ... ну, кмк, вполне себе имеет смысл задумка с объектами

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй так:

```
$st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Что-то я не понял как воспользоваться вашим ответом, вместо $User = $st->fetchAll(); поставил $User = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); но не вышло